# MaterializeCSS - Multiple Select - value stays in array after unselecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

When I unselect value in multiple selection in MaterializeCSS, it's still in the value array and I can't find a way to repair it. It works if I unselect option from original select with some function but $('.dropdown-content li').click() doesn't do anything so I can't just do something like

```
$('.dropdown-content li.active').click(function() {
    //take index of this and unselect option with same index from <select>
});
```

(please ignore the error on the screenshot, it's not related)

[image][image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and wrote a small workaround.
http://jsfiddle.net/9bL25jw9/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').material_select();
    $('select').change(function(){
        var newValuesArr = [],
            select = $(this),
            ul = select.prev();
        ul.children('li').toArray().forEach(function (li, i) {
            if ($(li).hasClass('active')) {
                newValuesArr.push(select.children('option').toArray()[i].value);
            }
        });
        select.val(newValuesArr);
    });
});
```